# Drupal Views: Access permissions by field

Tags: drupal-views

I'd like to hide one of the fields in a Drupal View from users that aren't logged in. This is easy to do for the whole block with the Access settings, but there isn't an obvious way to do it by field.

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't hide part of the block selectively, I hid the entire block from anon users, then created a duplicate of the block with the field for registered users removed, viewable only by anon users. This isn't ideal, but it works.